# What was the attitude towards atoms around the turn of the nineteenth century?

Tags: physics, atomic-theory

Einstein invented, on his own, a statistical mechanics, presupposing the existence of atoms. I can't imagine he was unaware of the shortly-before-invented statistical approach by Boltzmann and others, but then again the internet days hadn't arrived yet. [Einstein and the most elemental atomic theory](https://www.ans.org/news/article-969/albert-einstein-and-the-most-elemental-atomic-theory/#:%7E:text=Einstein%20also%20in%201905%20mathematically,use%20of%20statistics%20and%20probability.&text=Atomic%20theory%20says%20that%20any,always%20in%20random%2C%20ceaseless%20motion.)

Einstein pointed to the motion of Brownian particles, an effect already seen in 1827:

> In 1827, the Scottish botanist Robert Brown looked through a microscope at pollen grains suspended in water and discovered what we now call Brownian Motion. It was an unintentional discovery. He was not looking for the effect that now bears his name, but was, rather, curious about reproduction.

I am not sure if this was already interpreted as atoms hitting the grains. Atomic theory existed since Democritus (and maybe even before, but we are unaware of that). So maybe it could have been already interpreted by using atoms (even if these atoms were very different from the present ones, being geometric forms with hooks).

Anyhow, Mach was an opponent of the atomic view. The thermodynamics before the statistical approach imagined continuous substances. These were supposed to be divisible until the end. People hadn't yet actually tried to do this. And this hasn't been done until the present day. The evidence for atoms was (and still is) indirect. A substance hasn't been actually cut up to single atoms.

The existence of atoms was later confirmed by other experiments (culminating in experiments showing the existence of quarks and recently maybe even the existence of sub-leptons as is maybe seen in the recent muon g2 experiment at CERN). A detailed model came into being.

How did the opponents of Einstein react to the evidence proposed by Einstein (the Brownian motion)? How would Mach have countered the experiments performed later on in the 20th century? Could they still stick to the view that atoms are not there?

Comment: "Attitude?" People liked them but didn't want their daughter to marry one

Comment: Mach's refusal to acknowledge atoms seems like more of philosophical thing than a science-based thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Mach#Philosophy_of_science The [evidence from chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_theory#John_Dalton) for some kind of an "indivisible unit" of any chemical substance already was very strong.

Comment: @SolomonSlow But he had a lot of scientific results to base his views on. What were these. Did he change his mind in the face of other experiments? Im not asking about the philosophy of atomism or continuism. These are pretty clear. You can always assume continuism. Even when dividing a substance. You can divide space infinite times.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Why they didnt want their daughter to marry one? What did they know about atoms? Seems a bit prejudicious...Atoms are much more reliable than many husbands and provide materialistically...But did they think they were for real?